# Output view field as link

Tags: views, 6, entities, navigation

I need to output a field in a view as a field, how can I make part of the path the value of a CCK field?

For example if for a given item, my CCK value = '19' how can I make my path automatically be website.com/directory/19?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you can use, in respective field settings of your view, the option `Rewrite the output of this field`. please see this example (in image) with a field `title`. you must replace `[title]` with the respective field tag, according the indication in `Replacement patterns > Fields`.

[image]